# Instagram Desktop Version Notification with no description at all

Tags: notifications, windows-10, instagram, windows-10-desktop

I am using Instagram Desktop Version. I downloaded it from windows app store.
However, sometimes I received notifications with no description at all. They only showed the time.

I wonder what it is. Can someone explain it to me? is it a bug or something?

P.S. my PC OS is Windows 10.

[Notification Bug?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/am2rH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah Happened to me as well, quite many times.

- First of all try using administrator account if you aren't using already, sometimes this issue occurs due to multiple *(windows)* accounts *(& installing instagram as admin but using it as a strandard user.)*
- I discovered through performance monitor that it's either a direct message, a story notification or sometimes something miscellaneous. Perhaps to promote the android version, instagram has blocked those notifications and perhaps they haven't done it rightly which is why it appears as *(an untitled)* notification rather than no notification.

> The main issue here is that Instagram has ended support to **windows *phones***

which also run microsoft windows 10 operating system. So subsequently they've also started giving less attention *(& support)* to bugs on **windows computers**, because **generally** 85% of the users are on Linux *(which includes android & api config)* and only 15% on windows or perhaps less. *Microsoft & Instagram* should work on this together because not only does it affect customer experiences but this might also lead to exploitation of uncovered security vulnerabilities in future.

*p.s; I hope I've answered sufficiently, if you think I haven't, feel free to comment or else upvote.*

*cheers*... //

Comment: thank you for explaining thoroughly. really appreciate it! :)